# Is there any way to "sticky" a file in subversion?

Tags: svn

We have been working with CVS for years, and frequently find it useful to "sticky" a single file here and there.

Is there any way to do this in subversion, specifically from TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** no.

**Long answer:**
Working copies are sticky to a branch by definition, as changing to a different branch means changing the base-Subversion-URL used to access the repository.

However sticky-revision files... that's not a concept that Subversion has.
See:

- [Subversion update command reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re28.html)
- Appendix A of the subversion book: [Subversion for CVS Users](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/apa.html)

One workaround might be to manually return the file to a specific revision after doing an update. Perhaps putting something like the following into a script.

```
svn update
svn update -r1234 that/particular/file.txt
```

Another workaround, as tweakt suggests, is to have a partial branch with just one file in it. This needs very careful management though and things can get a bit.. er... sticky :-)
, if you're not vigilant.

Answer (score 2):

You can technically "branch" as little as a single file if you'd like... you can use 'svn switch' on any level directory or file. SVN tracks resources on a per-file basis just as CVS does, so it can do 'sticky' to the same effect. Committing a working copy containing mixed paths has very different effects though.

See:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re27.html
- http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2002-11/0336.shtml